# Database class partial success can exceed governor limits?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, dml, database, allornone

I have a question about the partial success using database class.
My question is, if i exceed governor limits. Will the whole transaction be rolleback or i'll have in the database the records that were comitted before the limits?

For example:
case 1: I have a list of 3 records, with 1 record without a required field. Of course I'll have 2 records inserted and one error message returned by the Database.insert(records,false).

case 2: I have a very long list and I use the Database.insert(records,false) inside a loop. In one moment, I hit the governor limits. My question is... Will the whole transaction be rolleback? Or Will i have in database the records inserted before hitted reached limits?

Comment: Good question. Have you tried this in a dev org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot catch those exception, so if you hit a governor limit, the whole transaction will rollback.
The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm) states

> All DML operations in a transaction either complete successfully, or if an error occurs in one operation, the entire transaction is rolled back and no data is committed to the database.
> [...]
> This keeps the database in a consistent state.

However you should be careful when dealing with a catchable exception, because if you successfully modify you data with a dml and later an exception is raised and you catch it, the transaction is not reverted. This may lead to an inconsistent state of your data.
I.E.

```
try {
   // statements
   insert listOfRecords;
   // statements

   a null pointer happens here

   update someRecords; // this will not be executed
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something to handle the exception
}
// at this point listOfRecords has been added to the database, but someRecords haven't been updated.
```

You can handle such cases via [`Database.setSavepoint()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_setSavepoint) and [`Database.rollback()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_rollback) as described in [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you exceed governor limits, your transaction is immediately and completely rolled back. However, if a partial DML operation has an error, the governor limits will be rolled back for each retry attempt, and only the governor limits used on the last successful operation will count towards the governor limits. In addition, some usually fatal things, like assert statements, will simply abort the DML operation and not the entire transaction; you can check the return value from the database methods to see if the DML operation was successful, and any errors you may have gotten.